# lapply or a for loop for listing objects in R

Tags: r, function, for-loop, lapply

I was wondering if I can use either `lapply()` or create a `for()` loop to have my function below called `decimal(see below)` repeatedly (for the number of objects that I have) first `list()` and then control the the number of digits?

In other words, how can I **avoid writing:** `list( AA = decimal(AA, 7), BB = decimal(BB, 7) )`

**by using `lapply` or creating a `for` loop like:** `lapply(AA:BB, function(x) decimal(x, 7) )`

**Here is my R function:**

```
decimal <- function(x, k){

   if(typeof(x) == "character"){
    return(x)
    }
   format(round(x, k), nsmall = k, scientific = 
       ifelse(x >= 1e+05 || x <= -1e+05 || x <= 1e-05 & x >= -1e-05, T, F) )
  }

   AA <- .234
   BB <- .34789640

  list(AA = decimal(AA, 7), BB = decimal(BB, 7) )

  lapply(AA:BB, function(x) decimal(x, 7) ) ## This doesn't work correctly
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, you need to combine `AA` and `BB` into a vector first using `c(AA,BB)`. Then to get the proper names from the `lapply` we can just assign the `names()`:

```
vec <- c(AA, BB)
names(vec) <- c("AA", "BB")
res <- lapply(vec, function(x) decimal(x, 7) )
```

Checking against your desired result we see that this has the intended behavior:

```
identical(res,
          list(AA = decimal(AA, 7), BB = decimal(BB, 7) ))
#[1] TRUE
```

**Edit:** Timing `lapply` vs. `for loop`. For loop is slightly slower (even if we initialize to it's full length first):

```
library(microbenchmark)

###Storing for loop in a function
for_loop <- function(invec){
  res_for <- rep(list(NA), length(invec))
  names(res_for) <- names(invec)
  for (i in 1:length(invec)){
    res_for[[i]] <- unname(decimal(invec[i],7))

  }
  res_for
}

###Microbenchmarking
microbenchmark(for_loop(vec),
               lapply(vec, function(x) decimal(x, 7) ))

#                                    expr     min       lq     mean     median     uq     max neval
#                              for_loop(vec) 276.692 282.4660 314.3094 285.6735 327.1565 759.514   100
#     lapply(vec, function(x) decimal(x, 7)) 238.204 243.1215 264.2524 246.5430 287.5980 395.581   100

###Just because, showing the two results are equal:
identical(for_loop(vec),lapply(vec, function(x) decimal(x, 7) ))
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Mike, thanks, just for my info., code-wise, would n't creating a loop be more efficient to do this?

Comment: @parvinkarimi Not necessarily, I created some code which shows that the for loop is slightly slower. For loops in general aren't bad as long as you don't do things like grow the object with each iteration of the loop. Even without doing that however, it's slower (see my edits).